# ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41) Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index' for json file ,flutter

Tags: json, string, flutter, integer

I'm trying to get two int from JSON file

This is the api response

```
[
    {
        "New_V": 30,
        "Old_V": 29
    }
]
```

When I use jsonDecode to get these two int I get an error in the tagged code

I keep getting

> Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of
> 'index'

on the code line

> newV = vData['New_V'].toInt();

this is my code

```
isTheirUpdate() async {
   var vData;
   try {
     Response response =
         await get(Uri.parse('https://0000000000000/check_v.json'));
     if (response.statusCode == 200) {
       vData = jsonDecode(response.body);
       print(vData);
       int newV;
       int oldV;
       setState(() {
         newV = vData['New_V'].toInt(); /////////// I get error here "type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'"
         oldV = vData['Old_V'].toInt();
       });
       if (newV == KCheckAppVersion) {
         isTheirInternet;
       } else if (oldV == KCheckAppVersion) {
         showDialog()
       } else {
         showDialog()
       }
     }
   } on SocketException catch (_) {}
 }
```

There is something I miss but I don't know what it is
Can someone explain the reason and a fix for this line of code?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable are `string` and you can't use `toInt()` on `string`, try this way to parse to `int`:

```
newV = int.parse(vData[0]['New_V'].toString());
oldV = int.parse(vData[0]['Old_V'].toString());
```

also you are getting list of map not a single map so `vData` is list of map and you need to use it like this:

```
if((vData as List).isNotEmpty){
   setState(() {
      newV = int.parse(vData[0]['New_V'].toString());
      oldV = int.parse(vData[0]['Old_V'].toString());
   });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, I edited the variables but it didn't work I still get the same error `E/flutter (14157): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index' `

Comment: can you say how define newV and oldV? @HAmr

Comment: I'm not sure I got what you mean, but newV should be 30 as New_V value, and oldV  should be 29 as Old_V

Comment: no, I mean did you define your newV like this: `int newV = 0;` ?

Comment: Yes I did you can find it before `setState`

Comment: I updated my answer, check it out @HAmr

Comment: Sorry I have been out, Yes it worked great thanks, I didn't use if state just edited variables and it's working now. Thanks again.

Comment: glad to help, I recommended use that if condition, because when your list get empty it will through an exception.

Comment: Ok, I got it now I'll use it instead of variables, Thanks again :)